# MS Acess: max(Date/Time field) on query when field may contain 00:00:00

Tags: datetime, ms-access, max

I am trying to build a Query in MS Access that returns the last date/time for a given entity ID. Research shows that using the MAX() function on the corresponding field and using GROUP BY on the remaining fields appears to be the way to go.

However, this doesn't seem to work in the presence of values that hold 0 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds, as it shows those values as well. The query's SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT Int(Historico_Classificacoes.ID_Entidade) AS ID_Entidade, Max(Historico_Classificacoes.Timestamp_Classificacao) AS [Data da última classificação], Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Telefone, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Beneficiários, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Naturalidade, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Nacionalidade, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Morada_Singular, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Laboral
FROM Historico_Classificacoes
GROUP BY Int(Historico_Classificacoes.ID_Entidade), Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Telefone, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Beneficiários, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Naturalidade, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Nacionalidade, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Morada_Singular, Historico_Classificacoes.US_Indicia_Laboral
ORDER BY Int(Historico_Classificacoes.ID_Entidade);
```

The Historico_Classificacoes table currently holds the following data:

```
"ID_Entidade";"Timestamp_Classificacao";"Classificacao_DMIF";"Notacao_Risco_BCFT";"US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao";"US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais";"US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva";"US_Indicia_Telefone";"US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital";"US_Indicia_Beneficiários";"US_Indicia_Naturalidade";"US_Indicia_Nacionalidade";"US_Indicia_Morada_Singular";"US_Indicia_Laboral"
"62";20/9/2015 00:00:00;1;30;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0
"62";28/9/2015 10:43:38;1;30;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
"62";29/9/2015 17:52:24;1;30;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
"62";29/9/2015 17:52:40;1;30;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
"98";20/9/2015 00:00:00;2;15;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0
"98";20/9/2015 00:00:01;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

The query, when executed in Datasheet View, outputs the following:

```
"ID_Entidade";"Data da última classificação";"US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao";"US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais";"US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva";"US_Indicia_Telefone";"US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital";"US_Indicia_Beneficiários";"US_Indicia_Naturalidade";"US_Indicia_Nacionalidade";"US_Indicia_Morada_Singular";"US_Indicia_Laboral"
62;29/9/2015 17:52:40;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1
62;20/9/2015 00:00:00;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0
98;20/9/2015 00:00:00;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0
98;20/9/2015 00:00:01;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

There are duplicated records for entities 62 and 98, when only one record for each was expected. Am I missing something here? Why are the entries whose values hold 00:00:00 present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using an additional query as an intermediate step that identifies the MAX Date/Time combination for each group ID first, then a follow up query that pulls the entire record where that Group ID, Date and Time match, this will ensure you won't have to use `First` or `Min` on the rest of your fields, and you will always get the correct data

Answer (score 0):

You use `Group By` for the last fields like `US_Indicia_Morada_Singular` and `US_Indicia_Laboral`. You'll have to use `First, Last, Min,` or `Max` on these as well.

Comment: How much of a difference does it make if, say, I use Min for every other field instead of Max? Using GROUP BY on ID_Entidade, Max on Timestamp_Classificacao, and Max on every other field seems to produce the result I want... But is that truly the way to go, considering I'm trying to select the records with the most recent date?

Comment: No, then you will need a subquery to retrieve the details of the IDs of the latest date from the present query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your attempt (without the repeated alias)

```
  SELECT INT(ID_Entidade)             AS ID_Entidade
       , MAX(Timestamp_Classificacao) AS [Data da última classificação]
       , US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao
       , US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais
       , US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva
       , US_Indicia_Telefone
       , US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital
       , US_Indicia_Beneficiários
       , US_Indicia_Naturalidade
       , US_Indicia_Nacionalidade
       , US_Indicia_Morada_Singular
       , US_Indicia_Laboral
    FROM Historico_Classificacoes
GROUP BY INT(ID_Entidade)
       , US_Indicia_Pais_Constituicao
       , US_Indicia_Responsabilidades_Fiscais
       , US_Indicia_Morada_Coletiva
       , US_Indicia_Telefone
       , US_Indicia_Proveniencia_Capital
       , US_Indicia_Beneficiários
       , US_Indicia_Naturalidade
       , US_Indicia_Nacionalidade
       , US_Indicia_Morada_Singular
       , US_Indicia_Laboral
ORDER BY INT(ID_Entidade);
```

From you comments, here is SQL that is close to what you need. I have added the field "AnotherField" for you as you may or may not need to add field here.

This currently selects the whole record from the table, but only the single "most recent" record for each value found in the AnotherField is listed.

It may be that you need more that one field where AnotherField appears in the  SQL.  Think of the field you use instead of AnotherField  as being the fields that need to be used to find the maximum date record.

```
SELECT Main.*
  FROM Historico_Classificacoes AS Main
       INNER JOIN (  SELECT AnotherField
                         , MAX(Timestamp_Classificacao) AS [MaxDate]
                      FROM Historico_Classificacoes
                  GROUP BY AnotherField
                  )
                  AS MostRecent
               ON ( Main.AnotherField            = MostRecent.AnotherField
                    AND 
                    Main.Timestamp_Classificacao = MostRecent.MaxDate 
                  )
```

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.